# Downloading Sitecore as a non-certified developer

Tags: training

We need to create proof of concept that the idea of monitoring the file is feasible in Sitecore by installing a universal forwarder at the Sitecore server that will forward the log to Splunk.

We would need a Sitecore test box/sandbox that we can use where logging is configured. How can we get Sitecore test box/sandbox for our purpose?

Comment: Have you considered acquiring 60 days trial Sitecore license? https://www.sitecore.com/getting-started/developer-trial
Once you have that, you could download Sitecore installation and deploy it locally.

Comment: I tried downloading Sitecore but its giving me error that downloads are only available for certified developers. I'm not. Is there other way I can download the Sitecore for free trial?

Comment: Not directly for you question, but Sitecore uses log4net for its logging. It is very vanilla and can be configured to point at any syslog type service. I have used it on Loggly and Sentry.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 different solution to this question:

1. The easiest of all is using [Sitecore Test Drive](https://sitecorekakde.wordpress.com/sitecore-test-drive/) which is a azure hosted sitecore instance already setup with a Demo website. It has been uploaded on Microsoft app store and is available for a limited time.
2. Signup on [eLearning Portal](https://elearning.sitecore.net/), register for free sitecore eLearning course. In step 2 you will receive a sitecore installer file along with quick overview training.
3. And the last option is to drop an enquiry to [Sitecore Support](http://mailto:SitecoreSupport@sitecore.com) for getting the evaluation copy along with developer training license for Trial. For more information [Visit](https://www.sitecore.com/getting-started/developer-trial).

Answer (score 1):

Following document contains information for developers who would like to start on sitecore..

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/developer-getting-started-

> Getting up and running
>
> Some helpful steps when you first want to get started:
>
> Make sure you can log into profile.sitecore.net. This is your key to
>   being able to access so many things in the Sitecore world.
>
> Understand prerequisites with [Installing Sitecore 9](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/installing-sitecore-9-introduction) blog series. For a
>   video guide, watch [Install Sitecore 9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8CWDtPq5iw&list=PLBDqdodEhG7-9-hX5R_m2UAvpMKEZp-xY) playlist while you follow along.
>
> Download Sitecore 9 today from dev.sitecore.net. Refer to Release
>   information: Instillation Guide for details.
>
> Take a [free eLearning](http://siteco.re/2DZoQcV) course! This free course from Sitecore will
>   guide you through the basics of Sitecore and set you up for future
>   training and certification.
>
> Dig into the [Developer Documentation](http://siteco.re/2C485fp) for Sitecore 9. This technical
>   documentation will help you understand more about the platform and the
>   architecture.
>
> See enablement content from the most recent [Virtual Developer Day](http://vshow.on24.com/vshow/SitecoreGVS/).
>   We'll be sure to reach out when future developer events come around.